# Bounty is asking entirely new questions and is making the question too broad, what to do?

Tags: support, bounty, needs-more-focus

Per title: The description of a new bounty by the original author of the question is asking entirely new questions and is making the question too broad, what to do?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296904/javascript-block-third-party-cookies-until-acceptance-eu-cookie-law

On top of the fact that the original question might already have been borderline off topic, as it was quite clearly looking for a library, even if it technically did not say so.

Comment: Flag it and explain that to a mod; only they can close the question.

Comment: It is a work-order, not a question.  I suspect it won't be received well once it moves up towards the top of the bounty list.  Maybe we shouldn't stop that :)

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm not personally opposed to a "work order" as a bounty, although it should be attached to a legitimate question. Whether anyone wants to do the work for the bounty is up to them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can flag for moderator attention to revoke the bounty and close the question, it is clearly too broad (give me teh codez) as is.

Short of that, downvote if you like and/or leave a comment (both of which I have done).

Otherwise, there's not much that *can* be done, it is treated just like any other question besides the inability to close due to the bounty.

Comment: I once flagged a question for moderator attention with a bounty before and it got rejected because it wasn't 'bad' enough, although after the bounty ended it got closed in like 30 minutes, so I have grown a bit hesitant in actually flagging for moderator attention. Either way, done it none the less after all. Seriously, close voting should really be possible for questions with bounties~ ach.

Comment: @DavidMulder I would agree with that given the following two caveats: (1) The post is below some threshold, at least negatively scored, and (2) no answers currently exist.

Comment: @DavidMulder It's actually a much harder problem than it seems, and is very much open to abuse.  If you allow users to close a question with a bounty do you refund the bounty, or just have the author lose that rep?  If you refund the bounty then users can try to get their questions closed after getting an answer, or if it looks like they'll never get one, in order to try to get back their rep.  If you fizzle the rep, you allow for greifing in which people inappropriately close another's question (knowing it'll get reopened) just so they lose the bounty. (Note these are two examples.)

Comment: @Servy Yeah, read those discussions, but never was able to figure out why not just put the bounty on hold as long as the question is closed... if a question is actually bad enough to be closed permanently, then it was the stupidity of the bounty poster that caused it. If anything I think the current system is more prone to misuse. But oh well.

Comment: @DavidMulder: That's an idea I don't think I've heard; it might work out, although I expect it would require DB schema changes, which is perhaps not ideal for a fairly minor corner case like this.

Comment: @Servy Spitballing here: Maybe make the quorum for closing a bountied question significantly higher, or require a moderator to "sign off" on the closure?

Comment: @duskwuff If you're going to require mod attention anyway, one might as well just use the current system of "flag a mod and let them sort it out".  No need to require 5 people to ask for a mod to look at it first.

Comment: That question is showing up as closed by delete votes rather than moderator attention. What sequence of events actually happened here?

Comment: @merlin2011 It looks like a moderator closed it (removing the bounty) and then three 10/20K users deleted it.