# Why allow bounty on recently edited questions?

Tags: feature-request, edits, bounty

Inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294862/bounty-is-asking-entirely-new-questions-and-is-making-the-question-too-broad-wh?cb=1) i can only wonder about one thing: Why is even allowed to start a bounty on a low quality question (duo to a edit)?

Because of the special status bounty questions have, it is hard to fix or close low quality bounty questions. On top of that, a edit on itself can already draw new attention to a question, potentional making a bounty redundant.

If bounty are blocked up until, say, 24 hours after the last edit, we would have the chance to weed out poor questions before the unfortunate user waste rep on a bounty.

Comment: Sounds like an easy tool for someone to grief with and prevent a question from getting a bounty placed on it.

Comment: Are you proposing that a question will become low-quality when edited...?! How often has this really happened? Is this *really* something we need to worry about?

Comment: @JoeW Because that happens a lot? After the 4th meaningless edit, the paper trail alone would be enough to revoke edit rights on this person. Not to mention you need enough rep to make meaningless edits that wont get rejected, at that point you have enough tools to do harm anyway.

Comment: How often does a low quality post get edited just to place a bounty? How often does a post get edited into a low quality post in order to place a bounty? After a bounty is placed there is nothing stopping bad edits. If there is a problem post with a bounty then a moderator can still deal with the issue and correct it. The point is there is potential to use this to cause problems and no evidence that it will fix a real problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This won't change anything

1. Edit Question
2. Place Bounty

or

1. Place Bounty
2. Edit Question

Is there any real difference between these two processes?

You can't prevent people from placing a bounty after editing a question or from editing a question after placing a bounty as it has a much greater chance of causing harm then doing good. There are many valid reasons to edit a post and place a bounty on it at the same time. From simply placing more information in the post that will help provide a more clear picture to providing clarification that other users have asked for. This would prevent a user from improving their question and getting the extra attention they want it to have.

Comment: And for the *very rare case* someone tries to abuse the system (bypassing a question ban, for example, repurposing an old question for a bounty) you can always flag for moderator attention anyway.

Comment: I have edited this question just now and can not place bounty on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71113000/unable-to-call-an-item-parent-method-from-array-every-and-other-iteration-method - it was asked 17 days ago

Comment: my fault..START BOUNTY was bellow al the comments.